# React + Firebase: How to acces a specific child in the database?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

good morning!
I'm trying to access a specific data inside my tree in the firebase realtime database.
The tree look like this:
[Firebase tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzvMA.png)

adrieltosi is one of the users, there are others. I tried the code below but it returns the whole tree with all the users, including adrieltosi. In no time this will get too big.

```
const database = fire.database().ref(`/${username}`)
        database.once('value')
        .then(snap => this.setState( { haveReadItens: snap.val() } ))
        .then(() => console.log(this.state.haveReadItens))
```

I must add that `username` is retrieved from the username that is currently logged in and added to my react State, so it has a value of `adrieltosi` in that case. My goal is to retrieve the tree of the specific user and also add to my React State or maybe Local Storage so I can manipulate it.

I have also tried this and doesn't work.

```
const database = fire.database().ref().child(`/${username}`)
    database.once('value')
    .then(snap => this.setState( { haveReadItens: snap.val() } ))
    .then(() => console.log(this.state.haveReadItens))
```

Any ideas to help me? Thanks!!

Comment: Try without the `/` at the beginning of the keys, and also log the `username` to make sure that it is not empty at the moment the code runs.

Comment: It gives me Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Comment: So it is empty without the `/`. Log the `username` variable right before the call and see if it is empty. Perhaps your `state` has not been yet updated (*the `setState` is asynchronous*).

Comment: That seems to be the problem. I thought i have dealt with that. I used `componentWillMount`to put the username is State. And this code is inside `componentDidMount`.

Comment: Thank you for the attention. Maybe I'll store the username in local storage, see if it works

Comment: If you could share more of your components code (*and how it receives the `username`*) so we can see the flow we might be able to help more.